# Why bool shows the correct bit order while outputting the shift operation result directly doesn't?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I was doing a task in which I was asked to represent a number in the binary form.
I did know the basic idea so I implemented something like this.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define pb push_back
int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=31;i>=0;i--){
       cout<<(n&(1<<i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output was **00000000000000000000000000000420** for **n=6**.

However I changed my code to this

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;
   #define pb push_back
   int main()
   {
     int n;
     cin>>n;
     for(int i=31;i>=0;i--){
      bool a=(n&(1<<i));
      cout<<a;
     }
       return 0;
   }
```

And it was all good.Gave output **00000000000000000000000000000110** for **n=6.**

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with first code ?

Comment: The result is an `int`, not a `bool`.

Comment: But even after being int,shouldn't (n&(1<<i) return either 1 or 0 as we are taking & between the bit at ith positition of n and 1. ?

Comment: @Doubts Besides of the poorly chosen title in the 1st version, your question was well done. Congrats and welcome to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am sorry for putting up question badly.And thanks a lot I am overwhelmed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what that number represents.

```
6 = 110
4 = 100
2 = 010
```

You're correctly masking each bit, but the result of those ops are integers. When you output them, it will print powers of 2 instead of ones and zeros.
Boolean type coerces the value to true (nonzero) or false (zero), which becomes one or zero on output.

You would need to right shift by the loop count to avoid casting as Boolean or using a ternary.

Comment: Good answer. Drawing my hat.

Comment: @Esmeralda Salamone  what does ops means ? Sorry for poor english

Comment: Ops is short for operations. Referring to the bit wise operations used to isolate the necessary bit.